# Virtual PC (Program Developed on XP Runs on W7 Problem)

Tags: window, compatibility, operating-system

I have a developed a C++ application using 32 bit and it create a executable file. This project has uses some external library like window socket 32bit, Qt GUI and boost library. The dll is located at same directory with the executable.

I wonder how can i run this application on window 7.

MY window 7 version is Home Premium 64 bit. Therefore, i cannot install the XP mode from Virtual PC but some one them reported that using Sun virtual box is functional.

I have try to troubleshoot the executable file using program compatibility but the problem doesn't solve.

Any program that can check external dependencies and identified the issues of running my program on window 7 ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: IMHO you already have an answer - install Sun Virtualbox in Win7, make an XP virtual machine inside, try to run your app inside. If there's a problem with that, modify your question :)

Comment: I looking for better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64 bit editions of windows can run 32 bit applications fine.  You just need to install the 32 bit versions of the needed libraries and it will work.

Comment: This is all the library i have included. qtmain.lib
QtCore4.lib QtGui4.lib QtXml4.lib QtSql4.lib QtOpenGL4.lib opengl32.lib glu32.lib QtNetwork4.lib QtScript4.lib QtXmlPatterns4.lib QtTest4.lib libpjproject-i386-Win32 vc8-Release.lib wsock32.lib ws2_32.lib   Can you please suggest which library i need to install 

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Any program that used to identified the external library dependencies which is unresolved in current machine ? 
Therefore, i then know which file to install. 
Please help.

Comment: AFAIK, the .lib is static linking into the final binary executable. Why it will cause this kind of problem ? 

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It may not be a 32 vs 64 bit problem.  What exact error are you getting when the app fails to run?